# Sending emails via smtp with phpmailer

Tags: php, smtp, mailer

I've a problem with PHPMailer and SMTP send mail. I wrote this code but it doesn't work on my script. I have two version of mailer, and the first one works without SMTP, but I need to use SMTP.

1. Without SMTP version.
2. Second version added PHPMailer but when I press submit, it doesn't send anything, only stopped on loading:

---

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config.php');
require(dirname("/mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php"); // path to the 
PHPMailerAutoload.php file.

$mail->$fromEmail = NO_REPLY;
$mail->$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$mail->$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
$mail->$headers .= "From: ".$fromEmail. "\r\n";
$mail->$subject = $LANG["WBS_REGM_SUBJECT"];
$mail->mail($user_email,$subject,$details,$headers);

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->Port = "465"; // 8025, 587 and 25 can also be used. Use Port 465 for SSL.
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Username = "XXXXXXX";
$mail->Password = "XXXXXXXXX";

echo '<div id="mode">1</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div id="mode">2</div>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<div id="mode">3</div>';
}
}
```

What I will do for use smtp? How can I fix this bug?

Comment: Post your actual code here, not pictures of your code.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: You can't use the full URL within the require function, use the local path instead.

Comment: It's very likely to be your require. You can't require that url.

Comment: Just a little note: You have error in your code. Missing `if` statement for your `else` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can not include the file by using the web URL. You may want to use the local path instead and then require it:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . "/path/to/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
```

To get the directory of current included file:

```
<?php
dirname(__FILE__);
?>
```

For example, if a script called 'database.init.php' which is included from anywhere on the filesystem wants to include the script 'database.class.php', which lays in the same directory, you can use:

```
<?php
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/database.class.php');
?>
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php.

The next step is to check if your server is configured to handle SMTP requests. Make sure the SMTP port you are using is open and can be used by your program.

Comment: Hi! thanks, but I did it but it didn't work. I've put this code with usr and without url.

Comment: What are the errors you get? Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in your code to view the errors.

Comment: I need send message via smtp, but I can't do it.

Comment: @oktamyoqubov Make sure the SMTP port you are using is open and can be used by your program.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! I've done.  This script called to db and I've fix it.

Comment: I would recommend you to use swiftmailer instead of PHPmailer. Swiftmailer is much easy to use and setup. https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-send-emails-using-swift-mailer

Answer (score 0):

Is your code on a web server or local? This can be a problem!

```
$mail->Host = 'localhost'
```

It may be a problem for the local code if you do not have a postfix email service for example.

```
mail()
```

Comment: My script on real server not local server.